# Solve the inital value problem $8(sin(t) \frac{dy}{dt}+cos(t)y)=cos(t)sin^4(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

consider 
$8(sin(t) \frac{dy}{dt}+cos(t)y)=cos(t)sin^4(t)$
for
$0<t<\pi$ and $y(\pi/2)=19$
Find the integrating factor and $y(t)$

Any help would be appreciated.

so distributed the 8
$8sin(t) \frac{dy}{dy}+8cos(t)y=cos(t)sin^4(t)$

then put into standard form

$\frac{dy}{dy} +cot(t)y(t)=\frac{1}{8}cos(t)sin^3(t)$

finding integrating factor

$ e^ {\int lnsin(t)}$ 
$=sin(t)$

Then I need to distribute correct?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\sin(t)y\right) = \sin (t)\frac{dy}{dt}+\cos(t)y.$$

Can you see how rewriting your left hand side in this way helps? You can figure out the integrating factor from this as well.

Comment: Can you explain what you did

Comment: @Alex it's a simple observation. Try taking the derivative of the left hand side. You should get the expression on the right hand side.

Comment: ok of the original or what you put?

Comment: What I put. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: Edit to what I originally had

Comment: This is fine. Notice that when you distribute you get your original ODE back and you'll get what I had above.